# cookie sets in postman but not in browser on localhost

Tags: vue.js, postman, authorization

I have an issue with cookies setting in postman when I make a post request to my route to login but unfortunately when I use the same info to login via my vue frontend I don't get a set cookie header in my browser or a token but rather it just returns and API key with a value....

not sure if anyone can help explain why this might be the case. Does postman run on localhost itself by default or do they use their own servers to route requests? just wondering if maybe that's the issue?

here's the code I am using to touch the endpoint in my view endpoint
**Note: I have a separate axios file with the root url** so the route only shows as /login just to clarify

```
 async handleSubmit(){
      const response = await axios.post('/login', {
        email: this.email,
        password:this.password
      });
      console.log(response)
    }
```

inside my console when logging it only returns an api key instead of a session id.
trying to dig around the postman docs to see if I can somehow use this key to get a session ID?
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#api-key

any help is greatly appreciated :)